# poist via open graph fail

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, connection

i'm tried topost via opengraph by using request.executeAsync() but **sometimes(very low rate)** i get response :

{Response:  responseCode: unknown, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, err
orMessage: null}, isFromCache:false}

I tried to debug  and  i found : when failed  i get an **INVALID_HTTP_STATUS_CODE** response.
I see in facebook refrence(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/FacebookRequestError):
*Indicates that there was no valid HTTP status code returned, indicating that either the error occurred locally, before the request was sent, or that something went wrong with the HTTP connection*.

So my question is:
 
**How can i sure** this issue from " indicating that either the error occurred locally, before the request was sent" or "that something went wrong with the HTTP connection"?

**note**: I checked my request many times. I see with same params , sometimes i can post successful but sometimes fail

Comment: Me too experiencing this issue . Create a ticket in Facebook support forum.[link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/165064080336162?browse=search_51a871f2416850f38770160)